# Codaset wiki markup

Tags: wiki, markdown, codaset

I'm sure this is a stupidly simple question, so I apologize in advance.

I'm playing with Codaset's wiki right now and trying to create a link to another page.  I was assuming that using a word like "AnotherPage" would automatically create a link to a new page, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Since I'm using Markdown with the wiki, I found that I can manually create a page, and then do a normal markdown link to it:

`[Another Page](anotherpage)`

Is that the best way to create a link from one wiki page to another on Codaset?  Their help only describes the basic Markup syntax, not how to create automatic links. Maybe it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Codaset wiki's use Gollum http://codaset.com/codaset/gollum. Please read the Readme at http://codaset.com/codaset/gollum for details on linking to other pages within your wiki.

Hope that helps you.